# How to show the tab bar when using Segue back in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have a Tab bar in the first view and a total of two views.

However, when I move from the first view to the second view and then back to the first view using the Segue, the Tab bar of the first view disappears.

When return to the first view from the second view, what is the way the Tab bar does not disappear?(without using unwind)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use *unwind segue* here. When you need to get back to previous ViewController, just `dismiss` your current ViewController

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) /* call this in second VC */
```

Comment: So what if there are three views? ex) 1p -> 2p -> 3p -> 1p (without using unwind)

Comment: @dinggu one way is using `UINavigationController` and simply `popToRootViewController(animated:)`, second is using delegate pattern: dismiss third and then dismiss second.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try what you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the [documentation](https://apple.co/2BHThnf) for understanding how combined View Controller Interfaces. Anyway, if you need to pop to previous view controller on the flow, you need to use

```html
navController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

But, if the need to pop up on the specific ViewController on the queue of View Controllers in the NavigationViewController, you need to use

```html
 navController.popToViewController(ViewController, animated: true)
```

From the moment you are using a NavigationController, a return button will automatically appear on the UINavigationBar, so you do not have to worry about that. Unless you want to customize the back buttons in the viewcontrollers queue, in this case use the above methods.

Comment: Where do you see `UINavigationController` in his question? Anyway, from ViewController you can get reference to current NavController using `navigationController` property

Answer (score 0):

It's for page 1. Display `tabBarController` once page is loaded.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
}
```

If click event is fired, hide `tabBarController`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "twoSegue") {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
    }
}
```